# Difference between class member definition with and without curly braces

Tags: c++, class, oop, emulation, member

Inside a class, if a data member is declared with curly braces:

`uint8_t registers[16]{};`

How is this different from declaring it without curly braces?

`uint8_t registers[16];`

Comment: uint8_t registers[16]{} will initialize all values in the array to 0. uint8_t registers[16]  will not.

Comment: In the case of an array, or any other aggregate type, the braces cause [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). Otherwise you get [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). [Here's a good rundown on all of the initialization options](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

Comment: Side note: `uint8_t registers[16];` may still fill the array with zeroes, depending on the scope in which the variable containing it has been declared and resulting [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).